# CSS: how to place controls at both extrems of a cell table

Tags: html, css

I've a button and a textbox inside a cell table. How do I do the styling so that both controls are positionned at the opposite. For now, the button stick to the textbox. I want them to be to the 2 extrems of the table cell.

```
<td style= "width:300px">
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>       
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<td style= "width:300px">
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="float:left;"></asp:TextBox>       
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" style="float:right;"width:100px; />
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the first one "style=float:left" and the second can be a float right.

This might cause the second one to appear slightly below in which case you should make it float right first.